# Ory Kratos Settings flow - 405 Method not allowed

Tags: angular, typescript, ory, kratos

I want to make a post request in Angular using the http client against the /self-service/settings/browser flow. However, I get the undocumented error "405 Method Not Allowed". Can anyone help me further on what the error could be?

I am using Ory Kratos self hosted in Docker container (oryd/kratos:v0.13.0)

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-Token': tokenGroup.attributes.value
  });

  this.httpClient.post(environment.kratosConfiguration.basePath + '/self-service/settings/browser?flow=' + this.flow.id, {
    method: 'profile',
    traits: {
      email: "max@exmaple.com",
      name: {
        first: "M",
        last: "M",
      }
    }
  }, {withCredentials: true, headers}).subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    }
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried using a more recent Ory/Kratos docker image?